# PL/SQL select statement based upon partial result set so far

Tags: sql, plsql

Is it possible in PLSQL in a select statement to access the currently partial result set onbtained.

For instance

```
ID table
ID1    ID2
1      2
2      3
3      4
5      6
```

select id1, id2 from id_table where "id2 is not already selected as id1 in the partial result set"

which will return

```
ID1    ID2
1      2
5      6
```

id_table is used for simplicity but in reality this is dynamically created as another query and not a table (hence the normal conditions can't be used).

It would be possible to do this in PLSQL employing a for each loop and a temporary table but this doesn't seem as elegant but this may not be possible.

Comment: Maybe you want LAG() function where id1 != lagged id2

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: Mihai that would be great if there was only one occurance but the general case is that there are multiple ids returned in ID2 per every ID1. ie 1,2 1,3, 1,4 may all be there